# How to implement multiple cell selection using RepositoryItemCheckEdit in Devexpress XtraGrid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui

Devexpress grid view repository checkedit auto-unselects immediately after I select next cell's checkedit.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ConnectDatabase()
    loadv()
End Sub

Private Overloads Sub loadv()
    Dim DataAdapter5 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet
    DataSet1.Clear()

    Dim str1 As String = String.Format("SELECT `id`, `Name` FROM `mydb`.`mytable`  ORDER BY Name ")
    DataAdapter5 = New MySqlDataAdapter(str1, conn)
    DataAdapter5.Fill(DataSet1)

  '  GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()

 '   GridControl1.Refresh()

    GridControl1.DataSource = DataSet1
    With GridControl1
        .DataSource = DataSet1.Tables(0)
    End With
    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub
```

This is my grid view:

[image: Form1 load view]

Here is the underlying DB table:

*Alerted table and uploaded new screenshot*
[image: MyDatabase]

How to implement multiple cell selection for `Passed` and  `ResultsPending` columns?

Comment: could you add a screenshot with edit marks of checked and the unchecked checkboxes?

Comment: I have created sample in vb.net and uploaded on google drive.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JyyZZteh3eNnNRVUJ1TmRoSWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: added two screenshot called capture1 and capture2 in above shared .zip file

Comment: add the screenshots to the question text pls.

Comment: shared folder.. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_JyyZZteh3eNHVtMmQyZUJxVmM?usp=sharing

Comment: @andrews I could not to find screenshot option here..

Comment: See "share edit flag" links under the question text. Choose edit and there in the editor click on the image icon. Then u will be able to add screenshots. Put ! sign in front of the picture reference and pictures will be displayed inline in question text.

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 columns with checkboxes `Passed` and `ResultPending` but you load only `ID` and `Name` from the Database. Thus, your 2 checkbox columns are NOT bound to data. They are called **Unbound Columns**.

You will have to maintain state for the unbound columns yourself.

So upon setting a checkbox you need to also record it's state somewhere in codebehind (in a `List` of some kind), then when the form is repainted, you need to provide that checked state data back to grid.

To achieve this explore:

1. [GridControl.CustomUnboundColumnData Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) - note it supports both read and write cases.
2. [Unbound Boolean column with the CheckEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E277)
3. [Behavour of CheckEdit with MultiSelect mode turned on](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q348511)
4. Search DX [support forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Search/) for more results using keywords: 'checkedit unbound'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still no luck if I added this query too.  Dim str1 As String = String.Format("SELECT  `id`, `Name`, `Passed`, `ResultPending` FROM `mydb`.`mytable`  ORDER BY Name ")

Comment: @newcommer, do you have those columns in DB? Originally, in your DB screenshot they are not present. Therefore, you needed to use Unbound Columns concept. Now, if you add those columns to DB, you should work with them as with normal, DB bound columns by properly specifying DB field names in the grid HTML markup.

Comment: can you please check now?

Comment: @newcommer pls also add your grid columns markup, do you have it right? In this case you need to update your DB table upon every checkbox click, because  in `loadv()` you call `GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()` and your checked state changes are lost.

Comment: To Save I will use  arrayOfGridChanges.Add(String.Concat(e.Column.FieldName.ToString(), "|", Convert.ToString(e.RowHandle))) in GridView1.CellValueChanged event.

Comment: still no luck if remove both GridControl1.RefreshDataSource() and GridControl1.Refresh()

Comment: @newcommer forget about markup, you don't have it probably. I need go offline now. It will be hard for us to find a solution like this, through many comments + SO doesn't recommend it. I will try to take a look at your project tomorrow if you don't find a solution by then.

Comment: I really appreciate it bro.

Answer (score 0):

1. Created binding source from toolbox.
2. Created New Untyped Dataset (named dsOnDesign using toolbox) and created table in dataset. Then created columns in table.
3. Assigned dataset as data source and table as data member to binding source.
4. Then assigned binding source to grid control by using properties.
   Now, I needed to bind dataset table’s columns to grid view’s columns.
   You may do it by opening “Grid designer”. 
   Click on Columns (Main view) -> pick columns and assign fieldname to each.
   You can see table columns in “Filed List” and Gird view’s columns in “Columns” group.
   Here’s my code:

   ```
     Public Class Form1
     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      MyBase.Load
     ConnectDatabase()
     loadView()
     End Sub
     Private Sub loadView()
   Dim enumerator As IEnumerator = Nothing
   dsOnDesign.Tables(0).Clear()
   Dim dataSetTemp As System.Data.DataSet
   dataSetTemp = New DataSet
   Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
   Dim str As String = "SELECT id, name, passed, resultPending FROM mydb.mytable"
   da = New MySqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
   da.Fill(dataSetTemp)
   Try
       enumerator = dataSetTemp.Tables(0).Rows.GetEnumerator()
       While enumerator.MoveNext()
           Dim current As DataRow = DirectCast(enumerator.Current, DataRow)
           Dim i As DataRow = Me.dsOnDesign.Tables(0).NewRow()
           i("ID") = Conversions.ToInteger(current(0))
           i("Name") = current(1).ToString()
           i("Passed") = If(current(2) Is DBNull.Value, False, fbool(CBool(current(2))))
           i("ResultPending") = If(current(3) Is DBNull.Value, False, fbool(CBool(current(3))))
           dsOnDesign.Tables(0).Rows.Add(i)
       End While
   Finally
       If (TypeOf enumerator Is IDisposable) Then
           TryCast(enumerator, IDisposable).Dispose()
       End If
   End Try
   GridControl2.DataSource = dsOnDesign.Tables(0)
   End Sub

     Private Function fbool(ByVal bool As Boolean) As Boolean
      If bool = True Then
         Return True
       Else
         Return False
      End If
    End Function
   End Class
   ```